# Expanding one single div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Hvvw7/

When i click on See More it's expanding all the divs. What should done for it to expanding only the corresponding div?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var rowsshown = 2;
 var rowheight = 1.2; // line height in 'em'
 var ht = (rowsshown * rowheight) - .5; // subtracting the .5 prevents the top of the next line from showing
 $('.info')
  .css({'overflow':'hidden','line-height' : rowheight + 'em','height': ht + 'em' });
});  
$('.aaa').click(function(){

        if ( $(".info").css('height') == 'auto') {
$('.info').css('height', ht + 'em');
} else {
$('.info').css('height','auto');
   $(this).hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).prev()` instead of `$('.info')`.  Using the latter changes all the elements as opposed to the corresponding one.

http://jsfiddle.net/zXffb/

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$(this).prev('div')` as your selector inside of your click event instead of `$(".info")` which will select evey element that uses the class `info`.  Seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hvvw7/3/

Typically I don't like this solution, but your HTML has kind of a weird structure for what you are trying to do so it might be your best option.

Comment: @Abe I just made it that way because that div is in a PHP loop :P  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is these lines:

```
$('.info').css('height', ht + 'em');
```

&

```
$('.info').css('height','auto');
```

What you are doing is selecting all of the DOM elements with the class `.info`, not just the one preceeding it.

I'd be using [jQuery.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) on your link div to get the preceeding info div.

Answer (score 0):

I think personally the cleanest way to address this is to assign id's to each .info class you have. then have your more links call a function instead of just running on all classes.

```
<div id="element_link_1" class="info">
    bunch of long text
</div>
<div id="link_1" class="aaa"><a href="#">see more</a></div>

$('.aaa').click(function(){
    toggle($(this).attr('id'));
});

function toggle(id)
{
     if ( $("#element_" + id).css('height') == 'auto') {
        $("#element_" + id).css('height', ht + 'em');
     } else {
        $("#element_" + id).css('height','auto');
        $("#link_" + id).hide();
     }
}
```

Comment: Alastair's answer would work also but I prefer not using jquery selectors for things that should probably be ID driven. Just because it is the nature of clients to rearrange things so if the dom changes at all someone will have to be aware of whether or not .prev() will be affected. My 2 cents is all.

Answer (score 0):

inside your `.click()` function for `.aaa` find the prev div instead of using `.info`

like this...

```
$('.aaa').click(function(){
    var $prev = $(this).prev('div.info');
    if ( $prev.css('height') == 'auto') {
    $prev.css('height', ht + 'em');
    } else {
    $prev.css('height','auto');
       $(this).hide();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/snitin_78/Hvvw7/5/) is a way of doing it...it hides the show more link for the current div, collapses all other currently opened divs and brings back there show more links.